# Changing MySQL charset to UTF8 on linux so it will work with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, utf8mb4

My application can be deployed on Win\Linux, and uses MySQL 5.5, and it may store data in different languages.

I changed my MySQL server to have the following charset variables set to UTF8:

- character_set_client
- character_set_connection
- character_set_connection
- character_set_database
- character_set_results
- character_set_server
- character_set_system

To do so, I added the following to my.ini:

```
[mysql] 
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'  
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

It worked well on Windows (MySQL 5.5.21 64 bit), but when my application run on Linux (MySQL 5.5.2 64 bit) I'm getting the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

Anyone knows where does 'utf8mb4' came from and how can I overcome this?

JDBC driver: 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin'

Comment: What is your mysql version on Linux?

Comment: MySQL version on Linux: 5.5.2 64bit

Comment: Try to upgrade it to 5.5.3 or higher

Comment: Check out if your MySQL is using /etc/mysql/my.cnf instead of my.ini.

Comment: Seems like MySQL is getting the configuration I'm changing, so I don't think it's a problem of using the wrong file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just to add to your `connection-url` params like:

> jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&characterResultSets=utf8

hostname -> may be `localhost` or any other host(you can specify with ip address `000.000.0.0`)