# Inserting Urdu Text in database but only "??????" inserted in database.

Tags: mysql, grails

I m trying to insert urdu text in database but only "????" insert in it. But in local host its worked fine. 
Problem is facing on remote server when i deploy war on Cent-OS server. 
MySQL server 5.5.15 is running on the Cent-OS server.

i also set character-set to utf8.

I had searched a lot on many platform to find the sol.
[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)
[Changing MySQL charset to UTF8 on linux so it will work with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683254/changing-mysql-charset-to-utf8-on-linux-so-it-will-work-with-jdbc)
https://serverfault.com/questions/61016/install-mysql-client-and-mysql-server-with-default-charset-utf8-to-fedora-11

I am trying from last three days.

I need a best sol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `accept-charset='ISO-8859-15'` in your form like that.

```
<form action="abc.php" method="post" accept-charset='ISO-8859-15' >
you form fields will come here
</form>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure collation of your column is set to **utf8**, what I use is **utf8_unicode_ci**.

To check the collation you can run following command.

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tablename
```

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';

with the help of these query i can see its utf8 character_set and utf8_unicode_ci collation. but i am still facing same issue of "?????" insertion in db when i deploy war on centos linux server.

Comment: What is the output of query that I have shared for your table ?

Comment: USE db_trunk;
 SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tblcorporateaccountivrs
    -> 


No Output....